# Issue with state management (PropertiesService) in Google App Script Chat Bot

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, concurrency, google-hangouts

I have a Google Hangouts Chat bot implemented using Google App Script. As expected, it basically receives a message, process it and responds. I persist the bot state for a given user using the PropertiesService. Before processing the message, the script reads the previous stored state, use it to process the message, updates the state, stores it and then return.

```
var STORAGE_KEY = "my_bot_storage";

function onMessage(event) {

  let message = undefined;

  if (event && event.message) {
    message = event.message.argumentText;
  }

  var lock = LockService.getUserLock();

  var success = lock.tryLock(5000);

  if (!success) {
    console.warn('Could not obtain lock after 5 seconds.');
  }

  var userData = PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty(STORAGE_KEY);

  botState = JSON.parse(userData);

  let bot = new Robot(botState);

  let response = bot.onMessage(message);

  var data = JSON.stringify(botState);

  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty(STORAGE_KEY, data);

  lock.releaseLock();

  return {
    "text": response
  }

}

function onAddToSpace(event) { // Does nothing }

function onRemoveFromSpace(event) { // Does nothing }
```

In addition to the the code above (Code.gs) I have a na extra script that defines the Robot class with a simple onMessage function that process the input and creates the output - the test version where I could reproduce the issue simply adds text to the original message and sends the result back. The basic setup follows the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script).

It works most of the time, but sometimes when processing a message, the state that is recovered is not the state saved by the previous message. I added logs to confirm the exact time properties are read and saved, and according to logs the state for a message is always saved before the state is read for the following message.

I thought that the logs could be hiding the actual persistence transaction, then I added code to lock the script - assuming there was a concurrent issue. But that did not work. At the end of the day, if PropertiesService is asynchronous I assume the lock would not work anyway.

Any idea of what can be happening?

Comment: Hi ! I have tried to reproduce your issue with the code you provided but I could not manage to get the bot to work (with the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/hangouts/chat/how-tos/bots-apps-script) guide however, I could). I was getting the message the bot is not responding. Could you please provide a complete description of the set up process and any missing pieces of code? Also, what is your ```STORAGE KEY``` variable?

Comment: Can you use Dialogflow for NLP & maintaining state? It's way simpler than this.

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I followed the basic setup as well. I added a little bit more details.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks a lot for completing the information of your script, that has helped a lot for understanding the issue. However, I have tried to reproduce it following your instructions and the updated version and the bot is not working correctly. **Could you please also share your Robot class so that we have the same set up for testing and figuring out where the issue is ?** Also, have you tried running this without the class Robot, everything directly in the function? What is your expected output when someone writes a message, the bot returning this message back? Thanks a lot for your patience !

Comment: @MateoRandwolf I updated once more. But you were right: for this test the robot script simply adds text to the original message and sends it back.

Comment: Hi ! I was eventually able to reproduce your script but it worked well consistently (i.e, every time I sent a message the bot returned that message with the added text from the Robot class). The only thing that might be different is the class Robot, **let me know if I had it in the same way as you did**: ```var Robot = function(message){
this.onMessage =  function(message){message = 'This was your message: ' + message;
  return message;}
}```. So what is your issue, is the bot not returning the message the user sent sometimes? Maybe sharing an example of your script might clarify the issue?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf my issue is related to the robot state. Note that for every message I recover the state from PropertiesService and pass it to the robot. In theory the robot should update it - let's say by adding a timestamp - and adter processing the message I update the state. Sometimes, while processing a new message, instead of recovering the previous state, the robot is recovering the state before the previous, which makes believe that the previous state has not being saved yet, althought the save command returns with no error.

Comment: I think in order to understand your issue you **must** share the piece of code of your **Robot class** as I do not know what you do with the robot state when you call ``` let bot = new Robot(botState);```. Please show me what you do in this class with the botState from the ```UserProperties``` and how does that related in your code with returning the message.  Thanks.